# gpg --homedir change directory not working

Tags: gnupg

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server.  We installed gpg4win and it works. We can create public and secret keys and decrypt messages for those that have our public key.

## The issue

The gnu install defaulted to my user profile and we would like it to be under a generic one.

We created a directory `c:\gpg_keys`

According to the documentation on the gnu web site:

```
    gpg --homedir /my/path/ 
    to make GnuPG create all its files in that directory. " 
    When we run this command this is windows install: 
    gpg --homedir c:\gpg_keys\          the return is: 
    gpg: keyring `c://gpg_keys//secring.gpg' created 
    gpg: keyring `c://gpg_keys//pubring.gpg' created 
    gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
```

Here the process stops.

When we look at the target directory we have:

```
    08/28/2013  05:14 PM                 0 pubring.gpg    
    08/28/2013  05:14 PM                 0 secring.gpg.lock 
    08/28/2013  05:14 PM                 0 pubring.gpg.lock 
    08/28/2013  05:14 PM                 0 secring.gpg
```

4 files of zero length are created.

Is there any way to get the target directory for home moved?

Comment: For the record, `--homedir` works fine in Linux (tested in Xubuntu 22.04.1). I know that's not what you're using.

Answer (score 7):

The `--homedir` apparently does not work but the following does:

```
Home directory:
  ===============
  GnuPG makes use of a per user home directory to store its keys as well
  as configuration files.  The default home directory is a directory
  named "gnupg" below the application data directory of the user.  This
  directory will be created if it does not exist.  Being only a default,
  it may be changed by setting the name of the home directory into the
  Registry under the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\GNU\GnuPG using the
  name "HomeDir".  If an environment variable "GNUPGHOME" exists, this
  even overrides the registry setting.  The command line option
  "--homedir" may be used to override all other settings of the home
  directory.
```

checking with `--version` shows the directory has been changed.

Comment: Changing --homedir seems to mess up the key agent. It is a major bug in gpg4win, and it has been open for about two years now. I've submitted a bug report to their issue tracker: https://wald.intevation.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=11&aid=6528&atid=126

Let's home it gets some attention. I'd fix it myself, if I had the time and the slightest idea where to begin.

Comment: Setting the GNUPGHOME environment variable worked for me with GPG4Win 2.2.3.  The --homedir option did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The `--homedir xxx` option is just that - **an option**. It MODIFIES how some other command works.

As an example, if you have a directory `/tmp/gpg` containing keyring files and want to see what keys are in them, you might run something like this:

```
gpg --homedir /tmp/gpg --list-keys
```

In this example, `--list-keys` is the *command*, and `--homedir /tmp/gpg` is an *option* which modifies how that command works, i.e. what directory to look in for the keyring files.

When you ran `gpg --homedir c:\gpg_keys\`, you didn't supply a command at all, so `gpg` did exactly what it does if you had just run `gpg` by itself - tried to figure out what you wanted, based on the input it receives. It even *told* you that it wanted input, when it said this:

```
gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
```

Comment: Except `--homedir` does work on Linux without specifying such as `--list-keys` before it. Are you sure that's the issue? Yeah, it'll tell you to 'Go ahead and type your message', but if you press Ctrl+c, and look, it'll have written the settings to the specified location. It's possible Windows is or a different version was different, there.

Comment: It creates files under the `--homedir` directory if those files didn't already exist. The keyring files always start off as empty, and if the command you're running doesn't add any new keys, then the files will *stay* empty.

The *order* of the arguments may or may not matter. The normal order for most OS's (other than windows) is "options first", which is why my example above has the `--homedir` option before the `--list-keys` command. I haven't used windows regularly in years (and don't have a windows machine to check now) but I seem to remember their convention is "options last".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ready made solution in the form of a .reg file. Paste this into example.reg, edit, save, then double-click on the resulting file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\GNU\GnuPG]
"HomeDir"="c:\\edit this\\.gnupg"
```