# gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed, cannot kill gpg-agent

Tags: debian, gnupg, gpg-agent

`gpg-agent` constantly logs (every 2 seconds) into `syslog`:

`gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed`

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673717/gpg-cant-connect-to-the-agent-ipc-connect-call-failed) but it is really not possible since once the process is killed, it automatically respawns and I have not way of killing it permanently. I also tried `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` with the same result.

I am on Debian Stretch. How do I terminate this process? And why is `syslog` being filled with those messages?