# GPG error when updating - Metasploit - How can I fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, metasploit

GPG error while updating - Metasploit

```
# curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapid7/metasploit-omnibus/master/config/templates/metasploit-framework-wrappers/msfupdate.erb > msfinstall &&   chmod 755 msfinstall &&   ./msfinstall

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100  5495  100  5495    0     0  67839      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 67839

Switching to root user to update the package

Adding metasploit-framework to your repository list..gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
Updating package cache..W: GPG error: http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CDFB5FA52007B954
E: The repository 'http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease' is not signed.
OK
Checking for and installing update..
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package metasploit-framework
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this on Ubuntu running on WSL 2.0 (or maybe even if you aren't) remove the gpg package and install the gnupg1 package instead.

```
sudo apt remove gpg
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y gnupg1
```

See more detail at

[gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673717/gpg-cant-connect-to-the-agent-ipc-connect-call-failed)