# How to generate PGP key in Azure Linux host

Tags: azure, gnupg, azure-linux

In the Web SSH console for my Azure Linux host, the following command:

```
gpg --homedir=$homeDir --batch --gen-key pgp-params.txt
```

results in this:

```
gpg: error running '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': exit status 2
gpg: failed to start agent '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': General error
gpg: can't connect to the agent: General error
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No agent running
gpg: key generation failed: No agent running
```

Running the same command in the Kudu Bash console

```
gpg --homedir=$homeDir --batch --gen-key pgp-params.txt
```

results in this:

```
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No agent running
gpg: key generation failed: No agent running
```

Either way, the following two files are generated, but nothing else:

```
private-keys-v1.d
pubring.kbx
```

**What am I missing in order to successfully generate keys in this environment?**

(Ultimately, I want to have my Azure Function App generate keys--I was running into problems which lead me to stepping through this in the various consoles)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to SSH into my Function App ran below commands and got the same error code as yours :-

```bash
apt install gnupg
```

[image]

```bash
gpg --gen-key
```

[image]

To resolve this error, I ran below commands and tried creating gpg keys :-

```bash
apt-get install -y gnupg gnupg1
cp -a /usr/bin/gpg /usr/bin/gpg2
ln -sf /usr/bin/gpg1 /usr/bin/gpg
gpg --gen-key
```

Results:-

[image]

And the Keys were generated successfully like below :-

[image]

Reference :-
[gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673717/gpg-cant-connect-to-the-agent-ipc-connect-call-failed) By Paxsali

Comment: looks promising, but attempting this with the --batch option seems to be causing an "invalid usage list" error. ?????